# How to calculate the square root of matrix $A+B$ perturbatively?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-analysis

$A=diag\{\lambda_1,...,\lambda_n\}$ and $\lambda_i>0$, $B$ is a positive definite symmetric matrix and  $max\{B_{ij} \}\ll min\{\lambda_i\}$

Note that the perturbative calculation of square root of $I+B$ is very easy, where $B$ is a small matrix.

How to calculate the square root of $A+B$ perturbatively?

Comment: $\sqrt{A+B}=\sqrt{A}(1+A^{-1}B/2)$

Comment: @CarloBeenakker This answer is not right. Because $\sqrt{A}(1+A^{-1}B/2)\sqrt{A}(1+A^{-1}B/2)- (A+B)$ is not a second order quantity.

Comment: What kind of "second order" do you want? $O(\|B\|^2)$ independently of $A$ might be difficult to achieve, since for instance we could have $A=0$.

Comment: Crossposted to http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/196448/2451

Comment: What does it mean to "calculate something perturbatively"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EDIT. Finally user34669 is right. We assume that $A$ is fixed and $B$ tends to $0$. The following $3$ lines are not correct because, in general, $\sqrt{XY}\not=\sqrt{X}\sqrt{Y}$.

"$\Delta=\sqrt{A+B}-\sqrt{A}\approx (A^{-1/2}B)/2$. We may also write $\Delta\approx (BA^{-1/2})/2$ or in a symmetric form $\Delta\approx (A^{-1/2}B+BA^{-1/2})/4$ and the formula is valid for $A$ symmetric $>0$ and $B$ a small symmetric matrix."

In fact, the previous approximations give an error in $O(||[A^{1/2},B]||)$, that is not interesting except if $A,B$ commute (we would like an error in $O(||B||^2)$ or at least in $o(||B||)$).

On the other hand, the other part is correct.

The function $S:X\rightarrow \sqrt{X}$ is defined and derivable on the set of SPD matrices. Let $K=DS_A(H)$ be the derivative of $S$ in $A$, where $H$ is a variable SYMMETRIC matrix. Here $SS=I$ implies $K\sqrt{A}+\sqrt{A}K=H$, a Sylvester equation in the unknown $K$.

i) A closed form. It is known that  $K=\int_0^{\infty}e^{-t\sqrt{A}}He^{-t\sqrt{A}}dt$. That implies that if $B$ is a small symmetric matrix, then $\Delta\approx \int_0^{\infty}e^{-t\sqrt{A}}Be^{-t\sqrt{A}}dt$, a symmetric matrix.

ii) Numerically, it is easier to solve directly the Sylvester equation diagonalizing $A$.

Answer (score 1):

See Theorem 3.25 on page 122 (as given by the page numbers) of http://www.renyi.hu/~petz/pdf/matrixPD.pdf

Comment: The assumption of continuity of the derivative is unnecessary.

Comment: The link is broken.